# Using ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, captivenetwork

The Android M supports a new [ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN). Is there any sample available on how to capture this action. I tried with the normal way of registering for an action in both through the activity and through the broadcast receiver. However when I am connected with the captive portal wifi network, I am not receiving the actions. Someone please help

Answer (score 8):

It can be used to allow your app to perform captive portal Wi-Fi sign in. Assuming you have something like this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SignInActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CAPTIVE_PORTAL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is what can happen:

1. Device connects to captive Wi-Fi portal
2. System displays a captive portal notification
3. User touches the notification
4. System displays the implicit intent app chooser
5. User selects `SignInActivity`
6. `SignInActivity` is launched

You may access the extras mentioned in the [`ConnectionManager.ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN) using [`getIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) and [`getParcelableExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)). Use the [`ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_NETWORK) extra (which has type [`Network`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html)) to communicate with the portal (*i.e.* pass sign in tokens), and the [`ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_CAPTIVE_PORTAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_CAPTIVE_PORTAL) extra (which has type [`CaptivePortal`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/CaptivePortal.html)) to communicate with the system about the outcome of the sign in.

Comment: I have that setup in the manifest, but always the default sign in page is launched, there is no activity chooser, I also made sure that there is no default app that handles the action

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? What device?

Comment: it's a galaxy J5 with 7.1.1 (25)